# Start new section at top of page, not below a figure

Tags: latex

When I use more than one figure per section in LATEX, I am no longer able to dictate that the section number start just after a page break.  I've been struggling with this for a while.  If there are any LATEX wizards out there, your help would be much appreciated.

In the file referenced below, it is section 2 that I am struggling with.  The final document is much, much longer than this and this problem happens several times, but I thought for the sake of clarity I would create a simpler version that still exhibits the problem.

[zip file containing everything](http://www.filedropper.com/sectionnumberplacement)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{placeins}

\widowpenalty=2000
\clubpenalty=2000

\begin{document}

\section{}


\begin{figure} [h]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=12cm]{Figure}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

My goal is to have section 2 start on a new page.
$$\\$$

\begin{figure} [h]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{Figure}
  \label{fig:example}
 \end{figure}


\newpage
\pagebreak [4]
$$\\$$


\section{}

\begin{figure} [h]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=14cm]{Figure}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}


This is the body text for section 2.


\end{document}
```

[Figure.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH6fA.jpg)

Comment: Section 2 *is* starting on a new page. But the figure is placed at the top of that page. I guess you want the section title to always be at the top of a page? Then I think what you need is to force the figures not to be placed at the top.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`?